# Merging two very similar PHP functions into one

Tags: php, function, global

I have two almost identical functions and I am not familiar with PHP but need just a bit of work around. I have several functions as the two shown here and I would like to know how can I merge both of them into one. I use PHP-5.4

```
function is_checked_gen($block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num) {
     global $gen_checked;
     global $gen_list;

     if (in_array($curr_rec[val], $gen_checked)) {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = 'checked';
              $gen_list .= " " . $curr_rec[val];
     } else {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = '';
     }
}

function is_checked_veh($block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num) {
     global $veh_checked;
     global $veh_list;

     if (in_array($curr_rec[val], $veh_checked)) {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = 'checked';
              $veh_list .= " " . $curr_rec[val];
     } else {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = '';
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to merge them, if they are identical? You just have to use one of them (and delete the other one).

Comment: They are almost identical. The difficult part is with the `global` array here which differs.

Comment: Do you want ONE function that checks all global variables (`$gen_checked`, `$gen_list`, `$veh_checked`, `$veh_list`)?

Comment: That would not be very useful because there are more such functions and I would like to keep the function as clean as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each function, only the corresponding list is getting updated when checked is found in the array. hence pass that list as reference and update it.

```
function is_checked($block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num, $checked, &$list) {

     if (in_array($curr_rec[val], $checked)) {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = 'checked';
              $list .= " " . $curr_rec[val];
     } else {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = '';
     }
}

is_checked($block_name, $curr_rec, $rec_num, $gen_checked, $gen_list);
is_checked($block_name, $curr_rec, $rec_num, $veh_checked, $veh_list);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you only check `$gen_checked`, which may differ from `$veh_checked`. I don't know why you omitted that.

Comment: How is this different from jurgemaister's answer (which was posted earlier)?

Answer (score 1):

The thing that stands out are the different global variables that are used in the functions. You shouldn't use globals at all, but that's out of the scope for this answer.

By sending the now global variables into the functions as parameters, you can merge them:

```
function is_checked($block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num, $checked, $list) {
    ....

    return $list;
}
```

Here, `$list` (formerly `$gen_list` and `$veh_list`) is returned from the function, so you can use this to update your variables from where it's called:

```
$gen_list = is_checked($block_name, $curr_rec, $rec_num, $gen_checked, $gen_list);
$vac_list = is_checked($block_name, $curr_rec, $rec_num, $vac_checked, $vac_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're going to have `$gen_list`, `$gen_checked`, and then `$veh_list`, `$veh_checked` you should make this into a class.

You could even put the `is_checked` method into the class.

```
class Type {
    public $checked;
    public $list;
}

function is_checked(Type $type, $block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num) {

     if (in_array($curr_rec[val], $type->checked)) {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = 'checked';
              $type->list .= " " . $curr_rec[val];
     } else {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = '';
     }

}

$gen = new Type;
$veh = new Type;

is_checked($veh, ...);
is_checked($gen, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is misplaced.
To merge two functions in a first of all you need if you're writing procedural or OOP.

Procedure should be divided into small services and add them to perform complex tasks.
OOP can use inheritance but here they serve a solid foundation before proceeding to refactor.

you must specifically identify common issues and refactor the one thing only

example not tested

//refactoring

```
fucntion is_checked_by($block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num, $obj_checked, $list_checked )
{


     if (in_array($curr_rec[val], $obj_checked)) {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = 'checked';
              $list_checked .= " " . $curr_rec[val];
     } else {
              $curr_rec['checked'] = '';
     }
}


function is_checked_gen($block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num) {

         is_checked_by($block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num, $gen_checked, $gen_list )
}

function is_checked_veh($block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num) {
      is_checked_by($block_name, &$curr_rec, $rec_num, $veh_checked, $veh_list )
}
```

this is just an example and not the best is just to make you understand OOP any funds

Comment: How is this object oriented?

Comment: no I just answered the question. writing classes without knowledge of the context do not think it makes sense ...

Comment: In that case, I would say that refactoring from using two functions to using three functions isn't very good refactoring.

Comment: questionable quality. but the quality of the refactoring (dynamic process) is not based on product code lines. the two functions can also disappear and rafctoring is mainly booby check_by. definitely improved ... :-)

Comment: I didn't downvote but this looks like something I would do in Java, and this wouldn't work because you still need globals for `veh` and `gen` variables to be visible.